# Elements not scaling properly when I zoom in and out

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a freecodecamp project and I can't seem to get any of the content to look normal when I zoom in or view it on my phone.

The "BTS" title is supposed to be on the center of the image but the text moves around and the image doesn't fill up the page all the way whenever I zoom in. Same goes for the circular images on the bottom. I'm trying to create two rows: 4 images on the first and 3 on the second row.

I have no idea what went wrong with my code.

What I included was only the parts that were messing up. The entire page is [here](https://codepen.io/hiashley-the-bashful/pen/XWapYOq?editors=1100)

```css
#img-div {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#title {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-family: "Bodoni Moda", serif;
  font-size: 200px;
  text-align: center;
 }
 #members {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 #members2 {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.smaller-image {
  width: 200px;
}
.border {
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
```

```html
<div class="container" id="bts-wsj">
  <img id="img-div" src="https://i.imgur.com/Th9Y0WO.jpg" alt="BTS-WSJ" style="width: 100%;">
  <h1 id="title">BTS</h1>
 </div>
 
 <div class="container" id="members">
 <a href="#"><img class="smaller-image border" src="https://i.imgur.com/HuZWnjV.jpg" alt="jimin">
   <p>Jimin</p>
 <a href="#"><img class="smaller-image border" src="https://i.imgur.com/yk5C7kz.jpg" alt="jungkook">
   <p>Jungkook</p>
 <a href="#"><img class="smaller-image border" src="https://i.imgur.com/JBEGNJw.jpg" alt="jin">
   <p>Jin</p>
 <a href="#"><img class="smaller-image border" src="https://i.imgur.com/7SJwU5t.jpg" alt="rm">
   <p>RM</p>
   
 <div class="container" id="members2">
 <a href="#"><img class="smaller-image border" src="https://i.imgur.com/pOFFDdi.jpg" alt="j-hope" id="hobi">
   <p>J-Hope</p>
 <a href="#"><img class="smaller-image border" src="https://i.imgur.com/tjMeZ9d.jpg" alt="v" id="v">
   <p>V</p>
 <a href="#"><img class="smaller-image border" src="https://i.imgur.com/MNB1YBS.jpg" alt="suga" id="suga">
   <p>Suga</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Html code, complete **div** and **a** tag. in BTS title to set mobile view use media query CSS so when you show your site in mobile view set as proper. Use this code to set your circular images in a row.

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #img-div {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    #bts-wsj {
        position: relative;
    }

    #title {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 30%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        color: white;
        font-family: "Bodoni Moda", serif;
        font-size: 200px;
        text-align: center;
    }


    #members,
    #members2 {
        width: 100%;
        background: white;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #members a,
    #members2 a {
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .smaller-image {
        width: 200px;
    }

    .border {
        border-width: 0px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
        #title {
            font-size: 150px;
        }
    }


    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        #title {
            font-size: 100px;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        #title {
            font-size: 50px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container" id="bts-wsj">
    <img id="img-div" src="https://i.imgur.com/Th9Y0WO.jpg" alt="BTS-WSJ" style="width: 100%;">
    <h1 id="title">BTS</h1>
</div>
<div class="container" id="members">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="smaller-image border" src="https://i.imgur.com/HuZWnjV.jpg" alt="jimin">
        <p>Jimin</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="smaller-image border" src="https://i.imgur.com/yk5C7kz.jpg" alt="jungkook">
        <p>Jungkook</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="smaller-image border" src="https://i.imgur.com/JBEGNJw.jpg" alt="jin">
        <p>Jin</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="smaller-image border" src="https://i.imgur.com/7SJwU5t.jpg" alt="rm">
        <p>RM</p>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="container" id="members2">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="smaller-image border" src="https://i.imgur.com/pOFFDdi.jpg" alt="j-hope" id="hobi">
        <p>J-Hope</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="smaller-image border" src="https://i.imgur.com/tjMeZ9d.jpg" alt="v" id="v">
        <p>V</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="smaller-image border" src="https://i.imgur.com/MNB1YBS.jpg" alt="suga" id="suga">
        <p>Suga</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The "bts" doesn't seem to move around now. However, the page still doesn't scale properly whenever I zoom in.  @Prashant

As you can see here: [https://imgur.com/a/Fqh2Iu5]

Comment: Ok, I understand your problem, please use the code I will update it. @manggae